# My css stylesheet in javafx is not working

Tags: java, css

I am trying to style a form in javafx using a stylesheet, but it is not working.

The stylesheet and the java class are in the same folder. I have tried using a styleclass and also with the id but it is not working.

This is how I included the stylesheet:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
Scene scene = null;
primaryStage.setScene(scene = new Scene(root));
scene.getStylesheets().add("sample/stylesheet.css");
```

sample.fxml

```
<VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" styleClass="vbox_inputs">
```

stylesheet.css

```
.vbox_inputs{
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

When I run the program everything works except the CSS stylesheet.

Comment: Try using `-fx-background-color` instead of `background-color`.

Comment: Thanks, it is working now.